# ViewController not conforming to a custom UIButton Class

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have a custom UIButton class that I'm trying to import into a ViewController class in my project but I'm receiving the error message:'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'OverrideButtonDelegate'"

Here is the code from the custom UIButton Class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol OverrideButtonDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
func overrideButtonDidStartPress(overrideButton: OverrideButton)
func overrideButtonDidEndPress(overrideButton: OverrideButton)
}

class OverrideButton: UIButton {
var delegate: OverrideButtonDelegate?

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    delegate?.overrideButtonDidStartPress(self)
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    delegate?.overrideButtonDidEndPress(self)
}
}
```

And here is the code from the ViewController where I'm getting the error message "Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'OverrideButtonDelegate'"

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, OverrideButtonDelegate {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you define the two functions in the delegate in the UIViewController? **When a class conforms to a protocol, the functions in the protocol has to be implemented in the class**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, OverrideButtonDelegate {

    func overrideButtonDidStartPress(overrideButton: OverrideButton)
    {
        //Code
    }
    func overrideButtonDidEndPress(overrideButton: OverrideButton)
    {
                    //Code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. This was exactly what I was missing.